# Wrong Reduce Outputs - MapReduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, mapper

first of all I'm a beginner in java but I have to complete a task with a MapReduce Job asap.

I have tried to modify the wordcount algorithm because the problem is very similar.

My input is a text file with a column of data like this one:

```
Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 1 

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 1
```

The MapReduce job must set the first string of each line like my key (Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:001) and the number 1 or 0 like the value.
The reducer's task is simply to sum the values( 1+1+0+1+0...) for the same key...that's all.
The problem is that in the result I obtain huge numbers (too big) like final values, but I don't know absolutely the reason.

This is the algorithm:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class MapReduce {


  public static class KeyValueMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Object , Text, IntWritable>{

  private IntWritable ValueDistanceFunction = new IntWritable();  
  private Text DateHourUser = new Text();




 public void map(Object key, Object value, Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
 while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
     DateHourUser.set(read.nextToken());
     ValueDistanceFunction.set(Integer.parseInt(read.nextToken()));    
     context.write(DateHourUser,ValueDistanceFunction);
     // I print the results only to check them
     System.out.println(DateHourUser);
     System.out.println(ValueDistanceFunction);
 }


  }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
      private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable>values,
            Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {    

int sum =0;

for (IntWritable val : values) {
  sum += val.get();
  System.out.println(sum);
}
result.set(sum);

context.write(key,result);
}
}



  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "KeyValue");

    job.setJarByClass(MapReduce.class);

    job.setMapperClass(KeyValueMapper.class);

    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/ubuntu/workspace/FileGeneration/Input"));

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/ubuntu/workspace/FileGeneration/Output"));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);

  }
  }
```

And these are exactly  the wrong outputs:

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 16

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 6

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 14

the correct outputs should be:

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 8

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 3

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 7

***the wrong result is exactly the double of the correct one***

Moreover, if I print the sum and the key with the value (0 or 1) during the computation I obtain this:

```
Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1 

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

8  (this is correct)

3  (this is correct)

7  (this is correct)


Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

1 

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

0

Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000 

1

8

3

7

16   (wrong final value)

6   (wrong final value)

14   (wrong final value)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your Mapper code. Why are you reading the input in the mapper?

Following lines have the problem:

```
BufferedReader sc=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/ubuntu/workspace/FileGeneration/Input/Input"));
String line; 
while ((line=sc.readLine()) !=null){
    StringTokenizer read= new StringTokenizer (line," ");
    while (read.hasMoreTokens()){
```

You have already specified the input, in the Driver class.

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/ubuntu/workspace/FileGeneration/Input"));
```

There is no need to read this input again, in the Mapper. Framework reads this file and passes each line to the Mapper. The line is contained in `value`.

Your Mapper code, should read like below:

```
 public void map(Object key, Object value, Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
     while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
         DateHourUser.set(read.nextToken());
         ValueDistanceFunction.set(Integer.parseInt(read.nextToken()));    
         context.write(DateHourUser,ValueDistanceFunction);
         // I print the results only to check them
         System.out.println(DateHourUser);
         System.out.println(ValueDistanceFunction);
     }
 }
```

**EDIT:**
I took your data and ran the program. I got the following result. I see no problem either data or code:

```
E:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\bin>hadoop fs -cat /user/mballur/Output/part-r-00000
Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000  8
Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:000  4
Date:2008-10-23Hour:04User:000  7
```

There is no problem with the program.

Comment: thanks very much , with your help i'm getting best results (smaller) but not the right results yet.
I mean , with your solution i don't obtain huge numbers anymore but the results are still incorrect....for example in my test( with a little input file ) i get:

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:001 15


Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 4

instead of:

Date:2008-10-23Hour:03User:001 8


Date:2008-10-23Hour:02User:000 2

DO you know why? 
sorry if I'm bothering you and thanks in advance

Comment: For testing purpose, run it on a smaller input (for e.g. 100 lines) and check. It is easier to debug with smaller input.

Comment: yes, I have done it with just 20 lines but the results unfortunately aren't correct..I don't know why

Comment: I don't see any more problem with the code. Are you sure, your input is correct?

Comment: Unfortunately the input file is fine...this is a mistery for me, even because the classic wordcount algorithm works very well...anyway, thanks very much for your help

Comment: I have just discovered a funny thing...
thanks to this line:
  System.out.println(sum);

i can check the intermediate values of the sum .
they should be just 3 because in my input test the keys with the same values are just 3...in the console i see:

8,
3,
7,
7,
2,
7,
15,
5,
14,

it is very strange because the "sums" should be only 3...and moreover the first three values are correct...8, 2 ,7 are the correct values...but after that something happens that generates 7 2 7 and then the final 3 values 15 5 14 that are just the sum (8+7 2+3 7+7)...but why happen all that?

Comment: I have edited my first question with all the input file and in the bottom there are also the right output

Comment: I have added in the first question also the print of key along with the sum:
Unfortunately I have already tried to comment the Combiner but the results don't change

Comment: Could be possible that the error is in the last line?

System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1)

Comment: the wrong results are exactly the double : 16 6 14 instead of 8 3 7 ( there was a line with a space in the input file)

Comment: I have checked the input a lot of times but it is perfect...I don't know where is the problem, seems that the code runs the mapreduce process twice ...but I can't find the reason

Comment: There is no problem with either data or the program. I ran the program with your data and I got proper results. Updated the answer.